# Get data from firebase database not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i m new in firebase and i m trying to get data from firebase database

**Database structure :**
[image]

**JS Code :**

```js
const userAnswersRef = admin.database().ref('/ChatbotProj/answers').child(userId);

return userAnswersRef.once('value')
  .then((dataSnapshot1) => {
    console.log("Fetching successed.");
    if (!dataSnapshot1.exists()) {
      return {}
    }
    var answers = dataSnapshot1.val();
    delete answers.lastQuestionId;
    return answers;
  });
};
```

I'm trying to get `answers` from the database.
The problem is that the code return `null` when I execute `dataSnapshot1.val();` even though that `answers` is not `null`

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are You sure that `userId` is not undefined or not null?

Comment: I don't see promise api from official manual: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data, so try this: `userAnswersRef.once('value', snapshot => { console.log(snapshot.val()); })`

Comment: yess  ! i even tried it with admin.database().ref('/ChatbotProj/answers/2042392955837498') and it didn't work

Comment: try to do it as in manual: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After answers you need to include "/", otherwise the resulting path would look like,

```
/ChatbotProj/answers12345uid
```

instead of,

```
/ChatbotProj/answers/12345uid
```

Set it like the example below,

```
const userAnswersRef = admin.database().ref('/ChatbotProj/answers/').child(userId);
```

Or, as I prefer to do it,

```
const userAnswersRef = admin.database().ref("ChatbotProj").child("answers").child(userId);
```

Comment: I ve changed it and i still get  the same result :/

Comment: What does it say in your log? Have you set the rules in the firebase console to allow you to read or write from the database? See the link here for Firebase documentation on rules. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: THANK YOUUU ! it was the rules !